# Reddit-style voting system, how do I avoid duplicate votes?

Tags: php, mysql, voting

I have a table that stores a post. Each post has an id, title, content and a score. Currently, you can like a post and its score will increment and decrement, if you dislike it.

Now the thing I don't understand: how do I avoid that a user will vote more than once? Surely they can just refresh and vote again. I've read some articles that store cookies, etc. but can't you just disable cookies or clear them and vote again?

I was thinking you would have to store who has voted, or rather, the ID of who has voted too. However, I can't seem to visualize how I would go about this? Would I store the ID of the voter in the post they're voting, or something else?

Comment: Check in a database if the user already voted that post.

Comment: Well that's what I was planning, but how would I store if a user has already voted on a post (that's the question)

Comment: A determined user - even one verified by an email address - can vote several times if they want to. You could require SMS verification, which is harder (but not impossible) to get around, but you may scare away real users who do not trust you with their telephone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an extra table `posts_vote` or something. Put the fields user_id and post_id in it. If a user votes a post up, you insert both IDs in this table. If a user votes down, find the record and delete it.

Comment: A cancelling downvote would require the record to be deleted, but another one (a real downvote) presumably would need a record for that.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer Yeah, I'd just check if the user has voted on the post and delete the vote record if they do?

Comment: @metro-man: if you want a Reddit style system then you need a record for a `+1` or a `-1`, and no record for a `0` (i.e. no vote, either because the user did not vote on a post, or they did and then cancelled it).

Comment: In this case I would use another field in the same table indicating the vote type. Store 1 or -1 in it. Would also make calculations much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the voting records in a separate table.

Vote history (Alternative 1)

- voter_id
- post_id
- action (upvote/downvote)
- created_at

Vote history (Alternative 2)

- voter_id
- post_id
- points (this field can get negative numbers for downvote)
- created_at

So when you have that particular record you can check if the user has voted for the post before and decide to increment/decrement the points in the actual post table.

In the future vote history table will grow and will cause you performance issues, you can sync history records with redis/memcached/etc. and do your checks faster with those storage technologies.

Also using cookies can help you to disable voting without hitting the server at all and will reduce the number of requests to your web server.
You can store the voted post id's in cookies and check them with javascript, don't do the request if user already voted the post.

So you can have two layers for checking if the user has voted.

1. Cookies and javascript
2. Server-side persisted data

If number one fails (users can bypass this via changing browser or cleaning cookies), it fallsback to number two and you don't allow to do the voting in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example:
Let's say you have tables `posts` and `votes`. Then you could have a `posts_votes` as a look up table.

Visually:
[image]